# count the frequency of items within a list based off a different implementation of the equals method

Tags: java, android, collections

I am using `Collections.frequency()` to count the frequency of objects within a list.
I overrode the equals method.
My use case object is a `MenuItem`.

The equals method it checks whether the name and other properties are all equal before returning true.

This works if that is the type of equals I want.

Sometimes I want to check whether they are equal based on the `MenuItem` id.

My issue is,
having already implemented the equals method,
I cannot use this with Collection.frequency().

How can I count the frequency of items within a list based on a different implementation of the equals method?

thank you

Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the implementation of `java.util.Collections#frequency`

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o) {
    int result = 0;
    if (o == null) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (e == null)
                result++;
    } else {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (o.equals(e))
                result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

it isn't that complex. You could create your own CollectionUtils class and define a method to get the frequency of a collection that accepts a Comparator as a parameter

```
public static <T> int frequency(Collection<T> c, T o, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    int result = 0;
    if (o == null) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (e == null)
                result++;
    } else {
        for (T e : c)
            if (comp.compare(e,o) == 0)
                result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```